# Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'void | Action | Observable<Action>'. when adding an effect

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

'run' gives error when adding the effects. Tried returning string, number etc. manually as well, but it does not work.

Effects code:

```
@Effect() 
getRoles$: Observable<Roles[]> = this.dataPersistence.fetch(CreateActionTypes.GetRoles, {
    run: (action: GetRoles) => {

       return this.formService
         .getRoles()
         .pipe(map(roles => {
           return new RolesLoaded(roles);
          }));
    },
    onError: (action: GetRoles, error) => {
      console.error(error);
      return new RolesLoadError(error);
    }
  });
```

Error message:

> ERROR in apps/app/src/app/+state/create.effects.ts(32,5):
>
> error TS2322:
> Type '*(action: GetRoles) => Observable*' is not
> assignable to type '*(a: GetRoles, state?: CreatePartialState) => void
> | Action | Observable'.
>
> Type 'Observable*' is not assignable to type '*void | Action | Observable*'.

Comment: What does run mean here ? Is this a rxjs operator ?

Comment: tried `.pipe<Roles[]>(..` ?

Comment: @TonyNgo https://nx.dev/angular/guides/misc-data-persistence

Comment: @naveen Yes, it doesn't work with this as well.

Comment: It's weird. Maybe the imported `Observable` is not the right one? Something is not coherent between the title and the error message. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

An `@Effect`should return an observable of `Action` not a `Action[]`, just `Action`.

In your case, it seems to be a mix up between multiples concepts.

Here is an example of `@Effect`

```
  createProject$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(CREATE_PROJECT),
    switchMap(({ name, id }) => this.myService.createProject(name, id).pipe(
      concatMap(project => [
        CREATE_PROJECT_SUCCESS(project),
        NAVIGATE({ path: ['foo', project.id] })
      ]),
      catchHttpError()
    )),
  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what getRoles() returns . I had a similar error. if getRoles() returns promise don't use pipe.

```
return this.formService
     .getRoles().then(()=>{
        return {type: TYPEACTION} 
})
```